# Adding extra fields in sign up form (Meteor)

Tags: meteor, config

I want to add some extra fields in my signup form and I found the code and did everything that is written there.

**Custom signup options:**

https://atmospherejs.com/ian/accounts-ui-bootstrap-3

I copied the code, pasted it in client/config.js file but still it does not work. 
First, I thought the problem was of having both packages *twbs:bootstrap* and *accounts-ui*, but when I removed the *accounts-ui* package whole web app crashed (just a blank page appears).

Can anyone help me? I searched a lot, still did not find right solution.

Comment: If the app crashes, you should see errors in your browser's console. Copy and paste that error message and we can help you more.

Comment: The only error I get is **TypeError: Cannot call method 'config' of undefined**.  Browser's console is empty.

Comment: `meteor add ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3` and `meteor add accounts-password` should fix that

Comment: Already have them, but I updated them once more just to be sure. However, _Cannnot call method 'config'.._ and _C:\Users\Amina\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.9\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:245
      throw(ex);
            ^_  errors appear.

Comment: Why don't you have a look at http://meteorpad.com and set up your code there so we can see it and help you